# inotify - how should I handle a full event queue?

Tags: java, inotify

I'm a Fedora user currently making use of inotify-java to implement directory polling. I have the following code snippet:

```
InotifyEventListener inel = new InotifyEventListener() {

   @Override
   public void filesystemEventOccurred (InotifyEvent ine) {
      // code to handle - done
   }

   @Override
   public void queueFull (EventQueueFull eqf) {
      // this is the part when I'm not sure what I should do
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform the recovery actions specific to your application.

The "queue full" event happens if you're not retrieving events fast enough. Excess events are dropped, but you're notified of this.

You should think what would be the consequences for your application if you miss an event or two, and plan the recovery actions (e.g. clean the queue fast and do the rescan of the directory).